# get-winevent: add parts of extended data to scv-columns

Tags: powershell

i want to figure out which user, ip, workstationname connects remotly to a station. This could be seen in the eventlog eventid 4624 logontype 10 (remoteinteractive, such as rdp). When this case happens, i need some data from the message field, but only some not all.

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Path="c:\temp\raw_data\SavedSecurity.evtx";} |Where {($_.id -eq "4624" -and $_.properties[8].value -in 10)} |Select-Object -Property TimeCreated, Message |pause
```

I know i can get a lot of data with the provided code, also the remote-ip, remoteworkstationname, remoteuserid withhin the message field.

Here comes the challenge:
i only want *some* data from the message field:

```
TargetUserName testuser
TargetDomainName testlab.internal 
TargetLogonId 0xb6f45e 
LogonType 7 
WorkstationName testclientwin7 
IpAddress 127.0.0.1 
IpPort 64372

Message: Successful Login
```

Any ideas how to write them (only this fields, not the additional ones) to a csv file with headernames the same as the selected data-items?

thanks

peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any ideas how to write them (only this fields, not the additional ones) to a csv file with headernames the same as the selected data-items?

Plenty!

Here's the safest (although probably least obvious) - use an [`EventPropertySelector`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogpropertyselector.eventlogpropertyselector(v=vs.110).aspx)!

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Path="c:\temp\raw_data\SavedSecurity.evtx";} |Where {($_.id -eq "4624" -and $_.properties[8].value -in 10)} |%{
    $SelectorStrings = [string[]]@(
        'Event/EventData/Data[@Name="TargetUserName"]',
        'Event/EventData/Data[@Name="TargetDomainName"]',
        'Event/EventData/Data[@Name="TargetLogonId"]',
        'Event/EventData/Data[@Name="LogonType"]',
        'Event/EventData/Data[@Name="WorkstationName"]',
        'Event/EventData/Data[@Name="IpAddress"]',
        'Event/EventData/Data[@Name="IpPort"]'
    )
    $PropertySelector = [System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogPropertySelector]::new($SelectorStrings)

    $UserName,$Domain,$LogonId,$LogonType,$ComputerName,$IPAddres,$Port = $_.GetPropertyValues($PropertySelector)

    New-Object psobject -Property @{
        Message      = $_.Message
        UserName     = $UserName
        Domain       = $Domain
        LogonId      = $LogonId
        LogonType    = $LogonType
        ComputerName = $ComputerName
        IPAddres     = $IPAddres
        Port         = $Port
        TimeCreated  = $_.TimeCreated
    }
}
```

In the above code snippet, we use XPath location selectors to grab the relevant `Data` nodes from the Event's XML structure. If any of them don't exist, the corresponding variable will simply be an empty string

Comment: thank you @matthias R. Jenssen, i tried your code snipped, which works exept the following: a lot of Exeptions `Exception setting "GetPropertyValues": "Cannot set the Value property for PSMemberInfo object of type "System.Management.Automation.PSMethod"."
At line:13 char:75
+ ... mputerName,$IPAddres,$Port = $_.GetPropertyValues = $PropertySelector` and the Message has all the garbage i dont want. I need only the first sentence. "An Account logged on." and not the rest of the message.

Comment: @PeterCore Sorry, there was a typo (double assignment) in the script, please try again no wthat I've updated it

Comment: @matthias R. Jenssen, nearly perfect, thank you. just export to csv only fills the first column, i try to fix that. nice solution.