# How to Specify the Event IDs of the security logs for my PowerShell script to export

Tags: windows, powershell

I have PowerShell script that I found on GitHub [here](https://github.com/viperior/windows-event-log-auto-export/blob/main/export_log.ps1). I am trying to export security audit logs that have a specific Event ID rather than exporting all logs to a .csv file. I am new to PowerShell and can't really seem to find any further information on next steps or how I should approach this. I imagine that the change will have to do with the `Get-WinEvent -LogName $($EventType) | Export-CSV "$LogOutputCSVFilePath"` Line of code, however, i am not sure what the change would be. Any help is appreciated.

**My Current Code**

```
# Capture the script start time
$ScriptStartTime = Get-Date

# Set output location for CSV files.
$LogOutputDirectory = 'C:\Users\myuser\Desktop'

# Define Windows event log types to export.
$EventTypesToExport = @('Security')

foreach ($EventType in $EventTypesToExport)
{
    # Build the file path for the current log topic.
    $LogOutputTopic = "Windows Event Log - $EventType"
    $CurrentTimeUTC = Get-Date -Format FileDateTimeUniversal
    $LogOutputFileName = "$CurrentTimeUTC - $LogOutputTopic"
    $LogOutputCSVFilePath = "$LogOutputDirectory\$LogOutputFileName.csv"

    # Create a CSV version of the log data.
    Write-Output "Creating CSV version of Windows event log of type $EventType."
    Write-Output 'Target CSV file path:'
    Write-Output "$LogOutputCSVFilePath"
    Get-WinEvent -LogName $($EventType) | Export-CSV "$LogOutputCSVFilePath"
    Write-Output 'Finished creating CSV file.'
}

# Calculate script run time.
$ScriptEndTime = Get-Date
$ScriptDuration = New-Timespan -Start $ScriptStartTime -End $ScriptEndTime
Write-Output "Log export process execution time: $ScriptDuration"
```

I am currently operating on Windows 10. Any help is appreciated!

*Note: You can view these logs by going to the Event Viewer application on windows, selecting "Windows Logs" and then selecting "Security".*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-FilterHashtable` parameter with `Get-WinEvent`:

```
$filterTable = @{
    LogName    = $EventType
    Id         = 1,2,3,4
    StartTime  = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
}
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable $filterTable | Export-CSV $LogOutputCSVFilePath
```

**Note:** Due to a limitation in the Eventlog service API, you can pass at most 23 unique EventID's in one query, add any more and the event log returns no results.

Comment: This is great! Would there be a way to make it so it grabs info for the past day? Thank you again for the help!

Comment: @Buzzkillionair Yes, see updated answer - you can also specify an `EndTime` entry if necessary

Comment: Using an array of id's over invoke-command has a further level of annoyance.

Comment: Not to bother again, but would there be a way to specify the log on type? According to Microsoft "When event 4624 (Legacy Windows Event ID 528) is logged, a logon type is also listed in the event log. The following table describes each logon type." I am looking to find a specific type @MathiasR.Jessen Also, How do you find the specific name of the event so that it can find the event?

Comment: @js2010 Like I said, I am fairly new and got the base of this from github

Comment: @Buzzkillionair You're welcome to ask another question (or [peruse existing ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48526192/get-winevent-add-parts-of-extended-data-to-scv-columns/48527378#48527378)) :)

Comment: Will do shortly!