# EventLogPropertySelector Not Returning Extended Data From Event Object In PowerShell

Tags: powershell, xpath, get-winevent

My short term goal is to gather event IDs 40 and 42 with provider `Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager` from the log named `Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-**LocalSessionManager/Operational` then sort them based on the Session/SessionID. While I could try and parse the message property, I'm trying to use the **EventLogRecord**'s **GetPropertyValues** method which takes a [`System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogPropertySelector`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogpropertyselector.eventlogpropertyselector(v=vs.110).aspx) parameter. Also, the session ID shows up first labeled "Session" for event 40's message and shows up second labeled "SessionID" for event 41's message.

| Name | MemberType | Definition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GetPropertyValues | Method | System.Collections.Generic.IList[System.Object] |

I've see that in 2018 [Peter-Core](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48661414) and [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48527378) have both given answer on how to do this. Following their examples, I looked at the event provider's event template.

```
(Get-WinEvent -ListProvider Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager).Events|Where-object{@(40,42) -contains $_.ID}

Id          : 40
Version     : 0
LogLink     : System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogLink
Level       : System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLevel
Opcode      : System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventOpcode
Task        : System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventTask
Keywords    : {}
Template    : <template xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events">
<data name="Session" inType="win:UInt32" outType="xs:unsignedInt"/>
<data name="Reason" inType="win:UInt32" outType="xs:unsignedInt"/>
</template>

Description : Session %1 has been disconnected, reason code %2

Id          : 42
Version     : 0
LogLink     : System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogLink
Level       : System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLevel
Opcode      : System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventOpcode
Task        : System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventTask
Keywords    : {}
Template    : <template xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events">
                <data name="User" inType="win:UnicodeString" outType="xs:string"/>
                <data name="SessionID" inType="win:UInt32" outType="xs:unsignedInt"/>
              </template>

Description : End session arbitration:

              User: %1
              Session ID: %2
```

As a test, I created the following to try and get the Session ID from the event ID 42:

```
$strComputerName='PMV-SC01'
<# For those wanting to build xmlFilters try something like the following as it allow you to create them more dynamically
$xmlFilterBase=[xml]'<QueryList><Query Id="0"></Query></QueryList>'
## in a loop ##
$xmlSelect=$xmlFilter.CreateElement("Select")
$xmlSelect.SetAttribute("Path","$Logname")
$xmlSelect.set_InnerText("*[System[$($ProviderName)TimeCreated[@SystemTime>='$StartTime' and @SystemTime<='$EndTime']]]")
$xmlFilter.QueryList.Query.AppendChild($xmlSelect)|Out-Null
$xmlSelect=$Null
## end loop ##
#>
#I used the filter below to simplify the testing.
$xmlFilter=@"
<QueryList><Query Id="0" Path="Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager/Operational"><Select Path="Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager/Operational">*[System[TimeCreated[@SystemTime&gt;='2021-06-28T22:00:00.000Z' and @SystemTime&lt;='2021-06-28T23:00:00.000Z']]]</Select></Query></QueryList>
"@
$WinEvents=Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $strComputerName -FilterXml $xmlFilter -Oldest|Where-object{$_.Id -eq 42}
$WinEvents.count
# output is 10
$SelectorStrings= [String[]]@(
'Event/EventData/Data[@name="SessionID"]'
)
$PropertySelector= [System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogPropertySelector]::new($SelectorStrings)
$WinEvents|ForEach-Object{$TheSessionIds=@();$TheSessionIds+=$_.GetPropertyValues($PropertySelector)}
$TheSessionIds.count
#output is 1
# All of the follow also return nothing:
$WinEvents[1].GetPropertyValues($PropertySelector)
$WinEvents.GetPropertyValues($PropertySelector)
$1WinEvent=$WinEvents[0]
$1WinEvent.GetPropertyValues($PropertySelector)
```

There is no error message. The GetPropertyValues() method just returns nothing.
PowerShell Version: 5.1.14393.2457

| Windows | Edition | Version | OS Build |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Windows | Server 2016 Standard | 1607 | 14393.2457 |

*([`Get-WindowsVersion credit`](https://smsagent.blog/2017/05/18/find-the-full-windows-build-number-with-powershell/))*

My long term goal is generating something like following output. The request on this post is help getting values back from the **GetPropertyValues** method. I'd also like to use this method in other projects.

| SessionID | User | TimeCreated | ID | Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | MYDOMAIN\User.Name | 2021-06-28 07:35:54.4321 | 42 |  |
| 12 |  | 2021-06-28 15:35:54.4321 | 40 | 0 |
| 13 | MYDOMAIN\Other.User | 2021-06-28 11:12:44.1234 | 42 |  |
| 13 |  | 2021-06-28 13:01:12.5678 | 40 | 0 |

Comment: For others, while viewing, sorting, or filtering the Event object returned from `Get-WinEvent` the xml filter needs to use UTC time, as the time stored within the events appears to be UTC as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you examine a sample XML record you can see the path to the node is not under /EventData/Data. It took some fiddling but this worked perfect for me.

```
$xmlFilter = @"
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager/Operational">
    <Select Path="Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager/Operational">*[System[(EventID=40 or EventID=42)]]</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
"@

$SelectorStrings= [String[]]@(
    'Event/UserData/EventXML/User',
    'Event/UserData/EventXML/Session',
    'Event/UserData/EventXML/Reason'
)

Get-WinEvent -FilterXml $xmlFilter | ForEach-Object {

    switch ($_.id){
        40 {$SelectorStrings[1] = 'Event/UserData/EventXML/Session'}
        42 {$SelectorStrings[1] = 'Event/UserData/EventXML/SessionID'}
    }

    $PropertySelector= [System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogPropertySelector]::new($SelectorStrings)

    $user,$sessionID,$reason = $_.GetPropertyValues($PropertySelector)

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        SessionID   = $sessionID
        User        = $user
        TimeCreated = $_.TimeCreated
        ID          = $_.ID
        Code        = $reason
    }

}
```

Comment: I was so close! I had tried the following, but never exactly what you suggested. Thank you.
`[string[]]$Propq=@('Event/UserData/EventXML[@Name="SessionID"]')
[string[]]$Propq=@('Event/UserData/EventXML')`

Comment: I tried that too and was surprised it didn't work. I believe the difference is the extra namespace Event_NS. You're welcome!